# PHP form + select UPDATE to MYSQL table won't Update the row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with my update form. When you press the update button it always updates the top row of the table instead of the one you want to update. Using a jquery ajax sendForm function to do the update on the div when you press update. it worked before adding that function.
Trying to update other rows also reverts the change to the top row.

```
`
foreach ($pdo->query('
 SELECT *
  from SubPlaceViewer;
   ')as $row) {

      echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['placeName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['realName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['entID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['length']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['height']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fakesnow']."</td>";
    ?>

    <td>/* Changed form-id. Still doesnt d */
    <form id="changeSubPlace<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
    <select name='entID'>    
    <?php 
    foreach ($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM Ent') as $row) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['entID'].'">';
      echo $row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName'];
      echo "</option>";
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="SendForm('subplace', 'subplace', 'changeSubPlace<?php echo $row['name']; ?>');">update</button>
</form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>   
</table>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $sql = "call _newResponsabilitySubPlace (:_entID,:_name)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(":_entID", $_POST['entID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(":_name", $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
}    
?>`
```

The function:

```
function SendForm(page, go, form) {

$.ajax({
    url : 'includes/'+page+'.php', // där formulär inmatning hanteras.
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#"+form).serialize(), // serializes formulärets element.

    success: function(data){
        MakeRequest(go);  // den div som ska laddas efter körning.
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Don't see an `UPDATE` query in here. What're the contents of `includes/subplace.php`?

Comment: You're assigning the same `id` to every `<form>` in each iteration of `foreach` loop. `id`s should be unique, better use `class` attribute. Plus, you're not sending any value to the function that uniquely identifies a particular row.